# Php email script not sending

Tags: php, forms, email

`http://www.dorsetdesigns.co.uk/contact.html`

try the form it wont send a email to me. i am using a mail account associated with the domain

```
<?php

// Clean up the input values
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
$_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

$_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
}

// Assign the input values to variables for easy reference
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

// Test input values for errors
$errors = array();
if(strlen($name) < 2) {
if(!$name) {
$errors[] = "You must enter a name.";
} else {
$errors[] = "Name must be at least 2 characters.";
}
}
if(!$email) {
$errors[] = "You must enter an email.";
} else if(!validEmail($email)) {
$errors[] = "You must enter a valid email.";
}
if(strlen($message) < 10) {
if(!$message) {
$errors[] = "You must enter a message.";
} else {
$errors[] = "Message must be at least 10 characters.";
}
}

if($errors) {
// Output errors and die with a failure message
$errortext = "";
foreach($errors as $error) {
$errortext .= "<li>".$error."</li>";
}
die("<span class='failure'>The following errors occured:<ul>". $errortext ."</ul>
</span>");
}

// Send the email
$to = "contact@dorsetdesigns.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Form: $name";
$message = "$message";
$headers = "From: $email";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Die with a success message
die("<span class='success'>Success! Your message has been sent.</span>");

// A function that checks to see if
// an email is valid
function validEmail($email)
{
$isValid = true;
$atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
{
  $isValid = false;
}
else
{
  $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
  $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
  $localLen = strlen($local);
  $domainLen = strlen($domain);
  if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
  {
     // local part length exceeded
     $isValid = false;
  }
  else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
  {
     // domain part length exceeded
     $isValid = false;
  }
  else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
  {
     // local part starts or ends with '.'
     $isValid = false;
  }
  else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
  {
     // local part has two consecutive dots
     $isValid = false;
  }
  else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
  {
     // character not valid in domain part
     $isValid = false;
  }
  else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
  {
     // domain part has two consecutive dots
     $isValid = false;
  }
  else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
  {
     // character not valid in local part unless
     // local part is quoted
     if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
         str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
     {
        $isValid = false;
     }
  }
  if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
  {
     // domain not found in DNS
     $isValid = false;
  }
  }
  return $isValid;
  }

  ?>
```

This code submits the form and the code below is the form the reason there is so much code is to make the php safe. i think there shouldn't be any errors in the code but that could be the problem

```
    <form id="contactform" action="processForm.php" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="message">Message:</label></td>
        <td><textarea id="message" name="message" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Send!" id="send" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: you mind showing us some code ?

Comment: There are many similar questions on SO (and other forums). Have you consulted those?

Comment: Have you tried REDUCING your code to a small piece of code that exhibits the issue?

Comment: Now that you've posted the code, can you dump the values submitted from the form?  Try `print_r( $_POST );` at the top of the receiving script.

Comment: Are there any messages in php error log?

Comment: For one, your first `if()` statement has no opening and closing brackets `{}`.

Comment: im new to php @andrew_kozak i put that code at the top of the php and it did nothing. it says POST 404 not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the file `processForm.php` is not there where it should be.

When clicking on `send` it tries to submit the form by calling the url: `http://www.dorsetdesigns.co.uk/processForm.php`

And the response is like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /processForm.php was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

So check the file paths, it will surely work.

Comment: IT WORKS NOW THANKS and due to such a simple mistake